# How to update matplotlib legend text on mousemove

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib with draggable marker - legend should update the value by moving the mouse over the line:

[image]

I am trying to update the current value of my draggable marker in the legend of a matplotlib figure. The user can click on the marker and move it on the line.
This is implemented with event handling.

I want to update only the legend and not fire a command like `canvas.draw`, As I am animating the marker, and don't want to redraw the picture again and again.

Comment: This is now the third question in a row where you don't show any code and let other people do all the work for you. You did not [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) any of the answers you got. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text of a legend `leg` by selecting the appropriate item from its `texts` and set a new text, e.g. for the first legend item

```
leg.texts[0].set_text("new text")
```

An example for setting the x coordinate of the mouse to the legend would look like

```
leg = plt.legend()

def update(event):
    leg.texts[0].set_text(event.x)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", update)
```

The best solution not to redraw the complete canvas would depend on how the draggable marker is implemented.